# ASP.net Core Web API: KeyCloak server not even contacted

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, keycloak

I am trying to incorporate auth* in an ASP.NET Core Web API. I set up a KeyCloak server and am trying to add this.

In my `Program.cs` I have:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o => {
                    o.MetadataAddress = "https://MyKeyCloak/auth/realms/MyRealm/.well-known/openid-configuration";
                    o.Authority = "https://MyKeyCloak/auth/realms/MyRealm";
                    o.Audience = "account";
                });
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
```

And:

```cs
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
// Other setup follows
```

I created a simple test controller:

```cs
[ApiController]
public class AuthTestController: ControllerBase 
{
    [HttpGet("/test")]
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult AuthTest() => Ok();
}
```

Calling `/test` endpoint just results in a 401. From the logs I can't even see that my Web API is making any attempts to contact the KeyCloak server. What am I missing?

## Followup 1

I now tried this with Thunder Client (similar to Postman) which has an OAuth2 function. Generating a token with KeyCloak works, but my Web API doesn't seem to accept it:

[image: OAuth2 config]

This *gives* me a token, but calling the API with it still results in 401.

## Followup 2

I cranked log levels all up to debug and get the following errors:

```
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[9]
      AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was not authenticated.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware[0]
      Policy authentication schemes  did not succeed
```

I changed the setup a bit:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o => {
                    o.MetadataAddress = "https://MyKeyCloak/auth/realms/MyRealm/.well-known/openid-configuration";
                    o.Authority = "https://MyKeyCloak/auth/realms/MyRealm";
                    o.Audience = "aspnet-test";
                    o.TokenValidationParameters = new() {
                        ValidIssuer = o.Authority,
                        ValidAudience = o.Audience,
                        IssuerSigningKey = GetSigningKey(),
                    };
                });
```

And `GetSigningKey` looks like this (for testing purposes with hardcoded cert):

```cs
static SecurityKey GetSigningKey() {
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("REDACTED");
    return new X509SecurityKey(new X509Certificate2(bytes));
}
```

From the KeyCloak admin interface in my realm, I used the `Certificate` of both RS256 and RSA-OAEP to no avail:
[image: certs]

I thought using a `MetadataAddress` should handle all this for me, or shouldn't it?

It is still not working. Can anybody help?

Comment: Are you passing a suitable Bearertoken in the Authorization header of the request to the `/test` endpoint?

Comment: For the first test, I want a redirect to the login page and this isn't happening.

Comment: I just sent the initial client registration token, but also 401.

Comment: A Web API never redirects to a login page: it may be called by another service that has no way of interacting with a user.
In the Authorization header, you should send the access token (as a bearer token) you originaly received from the Keycloak server when the user logged in to the app that is calling the `/test` endpoint.

Comment: Debugging tip: In the JwtBeareOptions for the Web API, you can add an event to be executed when a request is received: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbearerevents?view=aspnetcore-7.0
In an `OnMessageReceived`event, you can set a breakpoint and e.g. check the incoming bearer token (`var accessToken = c.Request.Query["access_token"];`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question because then I can mark it as accepted in two days.

I finally got it to work. Here are the steps:

1. Create a realm or use one you want to use
2. In the realm, create a new client. Use the following settings:

- Client ID: The Client ID you want to use.
- Client Protocol: `openid-connect`
- Access Type: `confidential` (needed later to fetch tokens)
- Valid Redirect URIs: At least `http://localhost:6789/callback`, but for testing, you can use `*` (not recommended for production)
- Advanced Settings: Specify the `Access Token Lifespan` to have your tokens expire
- Authentication Flow Overrides:

  - Browser Flow: `browser`
  - Direct Grant Flow: `direct grant`

3. Save the page
4. Open the newly-appearing `Credentials` Tab
5. Make sure `Client Authenticator` is set to `Client Id and Secret`, and note the `Secret`
6. Here under `Roles` (not `Roles` in the navbar at the left) add the roles you want to use in your API
7. Create a user
8. Under `Role Mappings`, `Client Roles`, select the created client, and assign the desired roles to the user

Then, I added:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o => {
                    o.MetadataAddress = "https://MyKeyCloak/auth/realms/MyRealm/.well-known/openid-configuration";
                    o.Authority = "https://MyKeyCloak/auth/realms/MyRealm";
                    o.Audience = "aspnet-test";
                    o.TokenValidationParameters = new() {
                        ValidIssuer = o.Authority,
                        ValidAudience = "account",
                        IssuerSigningKey = GetSigningKey(),
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    };
                });
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

static SecurityKey GetSigningKey() {
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("(Certificate MD5 of the RS256 key)");
    return new X509SecurityKey(new X509Certificate2(bytes));
}

// below when the app is constructed:

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

The `GetSigningKey` method should fetch the certs endpoint from the Metadata Address and get the certificate from there for production use.

With this in place, I can fetch a JWT using the Thunder Client and use this JWT to access the API.